# Excel formula to findout if date is between two other date and get the value of next column of that row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got a table like this:

```
    A             B             C     
----------    ----------    ----------
12.10.2005    12.10.2006        1
12.10.2005    12.10.2010        2
12.10.2005    12.10.2010        3
12.10.2005    12.10.2010        4
12.10.2005    12.10.2010        5
12.10.2005    12.10.2012        6
12.10.2005    12.10.2012        7
12.10.2005    12.10.2018        8
12.10.2005    12.10.2020        9
12.10.2005    12.10.2025        10
12.10.2005    12.10.2026        11
```

and i want to findout if this date `01.05.2012` included between any dates in each row of A - B..

and if any match found then i'd like to get the value at same row's C column..

so the result should be:

```
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
```

so far i've done this:

```
=IF(A1:A11<=D1>=B1:B11; "There is a result." ;"No proper answer found.")
```

i still cant find a way to get the value at C in formula so what should i add this formula to achive that?

Comment: Would you like the output to be a list of numbers separated by commas? or would anything else suffice?  Also, are you OK with a large sheet filled with formulas, or do you need strictly a one-liner?

Comment: if i can get the first line that would be enough and it dosnt matter if they are split with commas or not i just need to get the values one way or another. And yes i m ok with large sheet filled formulas.

Comment: Will the dates always be in the form `DD.MM.YYYY` (or `MM.DD.YYYY`, not sure what format the date is stored)? Or is it possible to have `3.4.2009`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to be sure this uses the right date formats, but you can do the following:

Use another 2 columns ("E" and "F") for these formulae: `=VALUE(LEFT(A1,2)&"/"&MID(A1,4,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A1,4))` 
`=VALUE(LEFT(B1,2)&"/"&MID(B1,4,2)&"/"&RIGHT(B1,4))`

They convert dates in `A1`/`B1` to the Excel date format (and return the corresponding [serial number](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/datevalue-HP005209044.aspx)).

You can convert your `01.05.2012` to a serial number, as well, for comparing. We'll put this serial number in `$G$1`

In a third column, you can use the formula: `=AND(E1<=$G$1,$G$1<=F1)` (the serial number in `$G$1` is greater than the serial in Column "E" (date in "A") and less than the serial in Column "F" (date in "B")).