# If the number is selected from 1 to 22 numbers between two different dates, the data of that row will be selected and entered in the new column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on Death/Retirement Claim Calculation project.

I have a sheet which has four columns. The A column contains the date start and the B column date end the C column contains the BPS numbers and the third column contains the monthly premium. I want to put two different dates in the E and F column and BPS in Column G then I want to get match result of dates are equal or between  to the dates in column A and B then match the column C BPS and return the result of Column D  which is the monthly premium, will be selected and entered in the column H.

| A (Date from) | B (Date to) | C (BPS) | D (Monthly Premium) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-08-2007 | 30-06-2010 | 1 | 120 |
| 01-08-2007 | 30-06-2010 | 2 | 120 |
| 01-07-2010 | 30-06-2012 | 1 | 135 |
| 01-07-2010 | 30-06-2012 | 2 | 135 |
| 01-07-2010 | 30-06-2012 | 3 | 170 |
| 01-07-2012 | 31-12-2018 | 1 | 162 |
| 01-07-2012 | 31-12-2018 | 2 | 220 |
| 01-07-2012 | 31-12-2018 | 3 | 220 |
| 01-07-2012 | 31-12-2018 | 4 | 340 |

I am confused I tried Index Match but did not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel formula to findout if date is between two other date and get the value of next column of that row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884728/excel-formula-to-findout-if-date-is-between-two-other-date-and-get-the-value-of)

Comment: Show your criteria dates in `E` and `F` and show your desired output.

Comment: If you have `365` you can use the `FILTER` function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by this limitation in your title: *"If the number is selected from 1 to 22 numbers ..."*, but for the rest of your problem, see below a use of the `FILTER` function, available in `365`.

Formatting your data table as a `Table` with the name of `Premium`, you can use, in `I2`:

```
=IFERROR(
    FILTER(
        Premium[Monthly Premium],
        (F2 > E2) *
            (E2 >= Premium[Date from]) *
            (F2 <= Premium[Date to]) *
            (G2 = Premium[BPS])
    ),
    "No Match"
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer could you please convert this in excel 2013 formula I don't have office 365.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean about E, F must between the A, B.
If you mean A >= E and F <= B, then please refer below, if not, you may need to change the date compare log in below.

```
=INDEX($D2:$D10,MATCH(TRUE,IF($A2:$A10<=$E2,IF($B2:$B10>=$F2,IF($G2 = $C2:$C10,TRUE))),0))
```

Take Row 2 as an example:

1. You may do the compare on date, then compare are the BPS value equal.
2. Use MATCH to get the correspond row match the E2, F2, G2 value, in this case, would be 2(D2)
3. Then use the INDEX to get the D2's value.

This formula is an array formula, if you are not M365 version excel, you may need to press Ctrl + Shift + Enter to finish the cell instead of just Enter.
(Refer : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d)

Hope this will help.